# Error in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

This is part of the code in Global.asax I am getting a run-time error (invalid code) on the line marked below. Can't figure out why?

```
  If Not Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("crm/default.aspx") > 0 Then
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            sb.Append("<DIV ID=""splashScreen"" STYLE=""WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: 9999"">")
            sb.Append("<TABLE class=""page_border"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" cellSpacing=""0"" cellPadding=""0"">")
            sb.Append("<TR>")
            sb.Append("<TD WIDTH=""100%"" HEIGHT=""100%"" ALIGN=""CENTER"" VALIGN=""MIDDLE"" class=""page_content"">")
            sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;")
            sb.Append("Loading page.  Please wait ...")
            sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>")
            sb.Append("<IMG SRC=""/TOrders/library/media/images/wait.gif"" BORDER=1 WIDTH=75 HEIGHT=15>")
            sb.Append("</TD>")
            sb.Append("</TR>")
            sb.Append("</TABLE>")
            sb.Append("</DIV>")

      -- Getting a Run time Error on this line --------

            sb.Append("<script language=""javascript"">var k=document.getElementById(""splashScreen"");</script>")

      ---Even this line appears with squiggly line in the editor--

            sb.Append("<%Response.Flush%>")

         -----------------------------------------------------

            Response.Write(sb.ToString)

        End If
```

Comment: What happens if you comment this line?

Comment: `sb.Append("<%Response.Flush%>")` - you are writing server-side script into html response - makes no sense.

Comment: Don't know if the following will work, but I encountered a similar problem years ago with classic asp.  Break "script" into two.  Ex.  "<scr" & "ipt>".  Do that on both opening and closing.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CM Kanode is right - I've never seen this behavior before, but somehow the script tags are killing it - probably a security feature. Even though you're inside of a string, the `</script>` part of the string is killing it somehow. Splitting that out solves that problem. The other alternative here is to use a codebehind file for your global, instead of leaving your code in the .asax file - then you're in a pure VB environment, rather than in ASP.NET markup.

@Igor is also correct - your code block in the `<%Response.Flush%>` line is invalid - even though you're in a VB.NET string, you're still technically in a markup file, and the `<% %>` makes it seem like it's a code block - you can't have code blocks in an ASAX file like that.

As @Igor indicates, it doesn't make sense to write that out to the response anyway, since that's a server feature, not something that makes it to the actual response.

So you'll need to deal with both issues, maybe something like:

```
sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>var k=document.getElementById('splashScreen');</sc" & "ript>")
Response.Write(sb.ToString)
Response.Flush
```